# can we call the toString() method of the Object class for a String

Tags: java, string

can we call the toString() method of the Object class for a String

```
String string = new String("Hello");
System.out.println(string);
```

for a string the overrided method is called in the String. Are there any way to call the toString() method of the Object class for a String

I want to print out the memory address for the String object

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can you add more details about problem you are facing? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jiriS You would have to use System.identityHashCode(string).  string.hashCode() would use the override of hashCode().

Comment: `Object.toString()` outputs hash code, which may be related to address or may not.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Usually, although not guaranteed by contract, the implementation of Object.hashCode() uses the internal adress of the object.

Comment: Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you want to print memory address of String object?

Comment: @Taemyr: True, but I was commenting on the original question without "I want to print out the memory address for the String object"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not call the overridden method. However, you could mimic the output of the `Object`'s `toString()` (which basically only uses the hashCode) as follows:

```
string.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(string.hashCode())
```

*edit: As noticed by Taemyr in the comments, an even closer mimic, that does not use the `hashCode` defined by `String`, would be:

```
string.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(string))
```

Comment: But the `hashCode()` is also overridden in this case.. So it wont help I guess...

Comment: Use System.identityHashCode(string) instead?

Comment: @AbishekManoharan well yes, `String` does override the `hashCode()` - but even if the `toString()` method of `Object` were called directly, it would use the `hashCode()` implementation of the subclass. As I'm hoping that the OP does not depend on a specific `hashCode()` result, the output should be close enough.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.. Why?.. Well because that method is *overridden* , So based on *object type*, at *run-time*, the method from `String` class is *always* called

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, once a subclass overrides a parent's member (function or variable), you can't reach them from outside that class. that is the whole principle of encapsulation and inheritance (child classes having different behaviour than parent).